# Change Management , what should be ideal flow?

Tags: project-management, lifecycle

I am trying to devise an ideal work flow which involves client, PM , Configuration manager, team leader, developer , tester and finally the repository itself.

Who would control what,how will the information flow and what role should the PM have when a change is requested.

Comment: If you're the Project Manager then it's proper for you to outline the Change Management process, otherwise you are operating well out of your role.  Change Management is not a Developer-led process and if it is then you're project is bound to fail to deliver the intended benefits to the stakeholders.  Downstream changes is the leading cause of IT Project failure and cost overun.  It needs to be managed by the PM or a non-invested resource who can independently manage the process.

Comment: agreed :) ... however that does not answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very suitable starting point would be the Wikipedia entry on this subject:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_management_(engineering)

It does a good job of showing the general process flow and roles & responsibilities.  You may want to tweak it to your organization.